# Trouble coding a number of matrix models to run simultaneously

Tags: r, matrix

I made a matrix based population model, however, I would like to run more than one simultaneously in order to represent different groups of animals, in order that dispersing individuals can move between matrices. I originally just repeated everything to get a second matrix but then I realised that because I run the model using a for loop and break() under certain conditions (when that specific matrix should stop running, ie that group has died out) it is, understandably, stopping the whole model rather than just that singular matrix.

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions on the best ways to code the model so that instead of breaking, and stopping the whole for loop, it just stops running across that specific matrix. I'm a little stumped. I have include a single run of one matrix below.

Also if anyone has a more efficient way of creating and running 9 matrices than writing everything out 9 times advice much appreciated.

```
n.steps <- 100
mats <- array(0,c(85,85,n.steps)) 
ns <- array(0,c(85,n.steps)) 
ns[1,1]<-0
ns[12,1]<-rpois(1,3)
ns[24,1]<-rpois(1,3)
ns[85,1] <- 1
birth<-4
nextbreed<-12
for (i in 2:n.steps){
  # set up an empty matrix;
  mat <- matrix(0,nrow=85,ncol=85)
  surv.age.1 <- 0.95
  x <- 2:10
  diag(mat[x,(x-1)]) <- surv.age.1
  surv.age.a <- 0.97
  disp <- 1:74 
  disp <- disp*-0.001
  disp1<-0.13
  disp<-1-(disp+disp1)
  survdisp<-surv.age.a*disp
  x <- 11:84 
  diag(mat[x,(x-1)])<-survdisp
  if (i == nextbreed) {
    pb <- 1
  } else {
    pb <- 0
  }

  if (pb == 1) {
    (nextbreed <- nextbreed+12)
  }
  mat[1,85] <- pb*birth
  mat[85,85]<-1
  death<-sample(c(replicate(1000, 
                            sample(c(1,0), prob=c(0.985, 1-0.985), size = 1))),1)
  if (death == 0) {
    break()}

  mats[,,i]<- mat
  ns[,i] <- mat%*%ns[,i-1]
}

group.size <- apply(ns[1:85,],2,sum)
plot(group.size)
View(mat)
View(ns)
```

Comment: Perhaps set a flag for each matrix that determines whether it needs to be calculated or not. then test with an `if` within the loop

Comment: If there's dispersal between (let's say) spatial locations, can that re-colonize a site where extirpation has occurred? (am wondering if that is a consideration for NOT ignoring a group going forward by setting the whole matrix to 0)

Comment: Yes the ultimate aim is for dispensers to be able to revolonise - but if I just set that column to 0 and dropped the new dogs in if available that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As somebody else suggested on Twitter, one solution might be to simply turn the matrix into all 0s whenever `death` happens. It looks to me like `death` is the probability that a local population disappears? It which case it seems to make good biological sense to just turn the entire population matrix into 0s.

A few other small changes: I made a list of replicate simulations so I could summarize them easily.

If I understand correctly,

```
death<-sample(c(replicate(1000,sample(c(1,0), prob=c(0.985, 1-0.985), size =1))),1)
```

says " a local population dies completely with probability 1.5% ". In which case, I think you could replace it with `rbinom()`. I did that below and my plots look similar to those I made with your code.

Hope that helps!

```
lots <- replicate(100, simplify = FALSE, expr = {
  for (i in 2:n.steps){
    # set up an empty matrix;
    mat <- matrix(0,nrow=85,ncol=85)
    surv.age.1 <- 0.95
    x <- 2:10
    diag(mat[x,(x-1)]) <- surv.age.1
    surv.age.a <- 0.97
    disp <- 1:74 
    disp <- disp*-0.001
    disp1<-0.13
    disp<-1-(disp+disp1)
    survdisp<-surv.age.a*disp
    x <- 11:84 
    diag(mat[x,(x-1)])<-survdisp
    if (i == nextbreed) {
      pb <- 1
    } else {
      pb <- 0
    }

    if (pb == 1) {
      (nextbreed <- nextbreed+12)
    }
    mat[1,85] <- pb*birth
    mat[85,85]<-1
    death<-rbinom(1, size = 1, prob = 0.6)
    if (death == 0) {
      mat <- 0
    }

    mats[,,i]<- mat
    ns[,i] <- mat%*%ns[,i-1]
  }
  ns
})

lapply(lots, FUN = function(x) apply(x[1:85,],2,sum))
```